# Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor::getByEmail() magento2

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I am trying to update custom attribute in magento2 but i am getting error while running this

```
<?php
    
    namespace test\Org\Controller\Result;
    
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
    use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;
    use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
    
    class Result1 extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
    
         /**
         * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
         */
        protected $resultPageFactory;
        protected $curl;
        protected $resultJsonFactory; 
    
        /**
         * @param Context     $context
         * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            Curl $curl,
            PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
            JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
            CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
            )
        {
            $this->curl = $curl;
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
            $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;        
            return parent::__construct($context);
        }
    
       
    
        public function execute()
        {
            $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
            //$numtwo = $this->getRequest()->getParam('numtwo');
         $result1 = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
             $resultPage1 = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    
            
                    $URL = 'apiurl';
                   
                   
                    $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                    $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
                    $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
                    //set curl header
                    $this->curl->addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    //get request with url
                    $this->curl->get($URL);
                    //read response
                    $response = $this->curl->getBody();
                    $customer = $this->customerRepository->getByEmail($email);
                    $customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
                    $customer->setId($customer->getId());
                    $customer->setCustomAttribute('fin_cus_id', 'c123');
                    $customer->updateData($customerData);
                    $customer->save()
                    
                    $resp= json_decode($response, TRUE);
                    $block = $resultPage1->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('test\Org\Block\Index')
                    ->setTemplate('test_Org::result1.phtml')
                    ->setData('model',$resp['model_list'])
                    ->toHtml();
    
                     $result1->setData(['output' => $block]);
                   // return $response;
          //  $result->setData(['output' => $block]);
           return $result1;
        }
        
    }
```

Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor::getByEmail()
Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor::getDataModel() ,

Comment: There is no getByEmail method in \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface. You have to use the get method:

$customer = $this->customerRepository->get($email);

Also, there is no getDataModel method. Just set the data and than save the customer using the repository again: $this->customerRepository->save($customer)

Answer (score 0):

Use get() instead of getByEmail()

Replace This line :

```
$customer = $this->customerRepository->getByEmail($email);
```

With this one :

```
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($email);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            echo $exception->getMessage();
        }
```

The Above code will through Eception if no customer found witht he email provided

```
* @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException If customer with the specified email does not exist.
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the usage of CustomerRepositoryInterface in your code. The getByEmail and getDataModel methods are not part of the CustomerRepositoryInterface.

```
<?php

namespace test\Org\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory; // Add this line

class Result1 extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $curl;
    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    protected $customerRepository;
    protected $customerInterfaceFactory; // Add this line

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Curl $curl,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerInterfaceFactory // Add this line
    ) {
        $this->curl = $curl;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->customerInterfaceFactory = $customerInterfaceFactory; // Add this line
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
        $result1 = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultPage1 = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $URL = 'apiurl';
        $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
        $this->curl->addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        $this->curl->get($URL);
        $response = $this->curl->getBody();

        $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($email); // Use get instead of getByEmail

        // Use CustomerInterfaceFactory to create a new CustomerInterface instance
        $customerData = $this->customerInterfaceFactory->create();
        $customerData->setCustomAttribute('fin_cus_id', 'c123');
        $customer->updateData($customerData);
        $this->customerRepository->save($customer);

        $resp = json_decode($response, TRUE);
        $block = $resultPage1->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('test\Org\Block\Index')
            ->setTemplate('test_Org::result1.phtml')
            ->setData('model', $resp['model_list'])
            ->toHtml();

        $result1->setData(['output' => $block]);
        return $result1;
    }
}
```

In this code, I've replaced getByEmail with get to retrieve the customer by email. Additionally, I've used CustomerInterfaceFactory to create a new instance of CustomerInterface to set the custom attribute.